# C# API request (GiantBomb)

Tags: c#, wpf, api, request

I'm trying to use the GiantBomb API with C# WPF. The following query to API worked fine some days ago but it returns an error today. Here is the error :

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotifica ion(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
à WpfApplication7.MainWindow.d__1.MoveNext() dans D:\Documents\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication7\WpfApplication7\MainWindow.xaml.cs:ligne 47

Here is how I query the API :

```
        App.RootObject gamesFound = null;
        string jsonData;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                //query to API
                //response will be a string which will contain json data

                jsonData = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=MYKEY&format=json&query=" + "Klonoa" + "&resources=game&limit=100"));
                MessageBox.Show(jsonData.ToString());
                if (jsonData == null)

                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("JSONDATA_NULL");
                        return false;                        
                    }

            }

            catch (Exception er)
                {
                  System.Console.WriteLine(er.ToString());
                }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: There seems to be a thread regarding this at GiantBomb. http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/api-developers-3017/api-call-throws-error-403-forbidden-1496714/